# Specifying names of arguments with a function in R

Tags: r

What I want to do is the following: I want to write  a function, let's call it 'function_creator' with one argument: name, and some additional arguments, such that its output is a function for which the name of the argument is the argument I passed to 'function_creator'.

The following code-snippet illustrates how I would like function_creator to behave:

```
f <- function_creater(name = "y", y_min = 2, y_max = 3)
f
function(y) {
  y >= 2 && y <= 3
}
```

How do I do this in R?? I guess that something like sys.call() might be helpful but I don't really know how to proceed from there.

Comment: What use-case do you have? I.e. *why* do you need to create such functions? rlang’s [`new_function`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/new_function.html) may be of help.

Comment: I adjusted the example to what is basically what I want to achieve. Thank you for the suggestion but I not only want to know how to solve this but also t understand it.

Comment: What do you mean by "and then you assign it to the name"? :)  But I want the output to be looking like above, which I think is what you refer to as the name being a parameter of the function.

Comment: Understanding it is harder, you’ll need to read up on how [functions](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html) and [environments](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html) *really* work under the hood, and some [metaprogramming](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html) knowledge is also required. After that, `new_function` is conceptually quite simple: it just calls the `function` function (*everything* in R is implemented as a function! Including the `function` keyword!): `new_function = function (args, body, env) eval(call('function', as.pairlist(args), body), env)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph this is exactly why I am asking this question and I was hoping that an answer improves my understanding of all these concepts of whichsome confuse me at the moment.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit @KonradRudolph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rlang::new_function()` you can do this. This uses `exprs()` from `rlang` as well to create an argument with no default value (i.e., a named list with nothing in it. The body of the function is put in the `substitute()` function to swap in the values for the variable names.

```r
library(rlang)

function_creater <- function(name, y_min, y_max) {

  new_args <- setNames(exprs(temp_name = ), name)
  new_body <- substitute((y >= y_min && y <= y_max), list(y = sym(name),
                                                          y_min = y_min,
                                                          y_max = y_max))

  new_function(new_args, new_body)
}
```

Testing:

```r
> f <- function_creater(name = "y", y_min = 2, y_max = 3)
> f
function (y) 
(y >= 2 && y <= 3)
<environment: 0x000000001af5f518>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I want the name of the argument to be specified in the function_creater function.

Comment: Ah that was my mistake. It works but it does not do what I want it to do, i.e. changing the name of the parameter and not the name of the function!

Comment: I was misreading your question the whole time. Updated to I think what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

There are better ways to do this, but there's also the poor man's method: create a string with code and parse/eval it. I'm using `glue` for readability, but the same thing could be done with `paste`.

```
library(glue)

function_creator <- function(name = 'y', y_min = 2, y_max = 3){
  code_string <- 
    glue('
      function({name}){{
        {name} >= {y_min} && {name} <= {y_max}
      }}
    ')
  eval(parse(text = code_string))
}



f <- function_creator(name = 'bob', y_min = 10, y_max = 20)
f(bob = 11) # TRUE
f(bob = 8) # FALSE
```

Note: With glue, objects within {} are evaluated and the result replaces the {}, e.g. `'{name}'` is replaced with `'y'` within the string. Because of this substitution method, actual {s and }s need an extra { or } to escape.

Or, using the method of @Adam

```r
library(rlang)
function_creator <- function(name, y_min, y_max){
  new_function(pairlist2(name = ), 
               expr((!!sym(name) >= !!y_min && !!sym(name) <= !!y_max)))
}

function_creator(name = "y", y_min = 2, y_max = 3)
#> function (name) 
#> (y >= 2 && y <= 3)
#> <environment: 0x7f8d0eeda028>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>